Please help ID celtic movie title & song title for its lovers kerchief dance
I have googled this hundreds of times using a bunch of terms to no avail. 
Vaguely recall a Scottish/Irish-medieval-Gaelic/Celtic-period movie (film in English, probably made in US or UK, likely released in the 80's or 90's, at least it was a color film) 
At one point in the story, a young woman and a handsome rogue met after a gathering or after everyone else had fallen asleep at an encampment with a fire left burning for light. 
He asked her to dance, she played coy but eventually took his or gave him a handkerchief or scarf and they danced to a beautiful tune, all the while jointly holding the cloth. I think the song was called "Hold On" (object of dance - you aren't supposed to let go of the kerchief/scarf especially if you like the other person) and the background music might have included the pennywhistle.   
Sorry, I can't recall actors or titles. Give me a few more years and I won't recall that I even asked this question. Would love to know the movie but mostly for that very romantic dance & song segment.  THANKS in advance.
